# Popover not working in ngx-bootstrap 1.9.2

Tags: popover, ngx-bootstrap

I am using Angular5 + bootstrap 3.3.7 + ngx-bootstrap 1.9.2.

Modal popup is working fine but popover is not working anymore.

I have included ref in app module.

```
import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';

PopoverModule.forRoot
```

Can someone help me?